# Converting various date formats into a single date object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 with a `nvarchar(50)` column which stores different formats of date such as `'dd/mm/yyyy'`, `'mm/dd/yyyy'`, `'yyyy-mm-dd'`, etc.

Now I am writing a procedure that will convert/cast this column as a date type. Something as below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, Column1) as [Date]
```

But due to varying formats of date I tend to get the following error in my C# application:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

I know of a function `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_PARSE` which can solve this problem but it's only available in SQL Server 2012 and above. Any workaround for this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: How do you expect it to magically differentiate `dd/mm/yyyy` from  `mm/dd/yyyy` for dates before the 13th of the month?

Comment: Are you trying to solve this in Sql Server? Because in C# you could use the DateTime.TryParseExact using multiple formats specifiers

Comment: @MartinSmith Even I am wondering the same.

Comment: @Steve Yes I am trying to solve this in sql server as it is part of an inner query performing calculations based on the date. The data comes from an excel file uploaded daily and formats keep varying.

Comment: Is `CLR` an option?  (This would give you access to C#, and as suggested by Steve, this might be helpful here) Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I think you should solve the problem where it is produced. You need to force a common format to your excel file or refuse to process them

Comment: Well, you could try and brute force it, just testing it against every date format until it works.  But you'll still be in trouble.  Is `01/06/2015` Jan. 6 or June 1?

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I will just handle this through C# to accept the correct format of date.

Comment: c# can't help you if you can't decide if 02/04/2015 is the second of April or the fourth of February...